# Unify different fields and get top more repeated values

Tags: sql, union

I have a table with different columns of a same field like:

```
  ID |  Genre1  |   Genre2   
  1  |  Sci-fi  |   Drama
  2  |  Musical |   Sci-fi
```

How could I get the top 5 genres (taking into account both columns)?
I think a good approach would be get something like:

```
Genre      Count 
Sci-fi       13            
Drama        11
```

And then I would use "TOP" to this.

Right now I am using:

```
SELECT TOP 5 Genre1, count(Genre1) AS times
FROM Customer_Profile
GROUP BY Genre1
ORDER BY count(Genre1) DESC;
```

It works for one of the columns but how I could apply this in order to take into account both genre columns?
(I might need to use Union All but I don't know how).

Thank you

Comment: I'd advise fixing your data model, if possible. Data of the same "type" ought to be stored in a single column. If the `1` and `2` suffixes are significant, those also ought to be represented as queryable *data* in another column, rather than embedded in the column names. E.g. you should have a table with `ID, Genre, Ranking` columns and four rows for your example data (two rows each for IDs 1 and 2)

Comment: Tag dbms used. E.g. TOP is product specific!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UNION like this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 Genre,count(Genre) as Times
FROM(select Genre1 as Genre FROM Customer_Profile
     UNION ALL
     select Genre2 FROM Customer_Profile)
GROUP BY Genre
ORDER BY count(Genre) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `union all`

```
SELECT TOP 5 Genre, count(Genre) AS times
FROM (
    select Genre1 Genre
    from Customer_Profile
    union all
    select Genre2 Genre
    from Customer_Profile
) x
GROUP BY Genre
ORDER BY count(Genre) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT genre,
       COUNT(*)
FROM
(SELECT genre1 AS genre
 FROM   Customer_Profile
 UNION ALL
 SELECT genre2 AS genre
 FROM   Customer_Profile
)
GROUP BY genre
ORDER BY 2;
```